# How can I create numbered map markers in Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a map that has multiple markers on it.

These markers use a custom icon, but I'd also like to add numbers on top. I've seen how this has been accomplished using older versions of the API. How can I do this in V3?

*Note -- the "title" attribute creates a tooltip when you mouseover the marker, but I want something that will be layered on top of the custom image even when you're not hovering on top of it.

Here's the documentation for the marker class, and none of these attributes seem to help: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MarkerOptions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps: place number in marker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890670/google-maps-place-number-in-marker)

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37582234/3553665

Comment: This is possible with the version 3.21 of the API which introduced markers with labels, but only if you have < 10 markers because Google truncate the label text to 1 character. I raised a [Google Maps Issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578) to request that this restriction be lifted. Please star the issue if you'd like them to fix it - thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not very easy. You could create your own custom marker based on the OverlayView class ([an example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html)) and put your own HTML in it, including a counter. This will leave you with a very basic marker, that you can't drag around or add shadows easily, but it is very customisable.

Alternatively, you could [add a label to the default marker](http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html). This will be less customisable but should work. It also keeps all the useful things the standard marker does.

You can read more about the overlays in Google's article [Fun with MVC Objects](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html).

Edit: if you don't want to create a JavaScript class, you could use [Google's Chart API](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/chart-types-for-map-pins). For example:

Numbered marker:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=7|FF0000|000000
```

Text marker:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=1|0|FF0000|12|_|foo
```

This is the quick and easy route, but it's less customisable, and requires a new image to be downloaded by the client for each marker.

Comment: Thank you, Dave -- I've already solved this with numbered images (an approach I didn't want to use, but made the most sense given the time constraints), but I like the Chart API approach as well.

Comment: Using the Charts API is my preferred approach.

Comment: Do you have a quick way to create 1000 numbered icons with running numbers?

Comment: Awesome tip to use the Chart API... Thank you so much!

Comment: Be careful though, Charts API is scheduled to be depreciated in April 2015 - so in about 6 months.

Comment: you mean "Deprecated". Otherwise people can't find this word

Comment: This can now be done via the api with no third party code, I have posted an answer below.

Comment: Just to be clear, the entire Google Carts API was not deprecated, just the Image Charts and Infographics tools. But as John mentioned, this answer is about to be outdated anyway with the 3.21 release.  See John's answer.

Answer (score 47):

This how I do it in V3:

I start by loading the google maps api and within the callback method `initialize()` I load **MarkerWithLabel.js** that I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/?r=131):

```
function initialize() {

            $.getScript("/js/site/marker/MarkerWithLabel.js#{applicationBean.version}", function(){

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat, currentLng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'),
                    mapOptions);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0; i &lt; mapData.length; i++) {
                createMarker(i+1, map, mapData[i]); <!-- MARKERS! -->
                extendBounds(bounds, mapData[i]);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var maximumZoomLevel = 16;
            var minimumZoomLevel = 11;
            var ourZoom = defaultZoomLevel; // default zoom level

            var blistener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                if (this.getZoom(map.getBounds) &gt; 16) {
                    this.setZoom(maximumZoomLevel);
                }
                google.maps.event.removeListener(blistener);
            });
            });
        }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places&amp;sensor=false&amp;callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;

    </script>
```

I then create the markers with `createMarker()`:

```
function createMarker(number, currentMap, currentMapData) {

   var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(currentMapData[0], currentMapData[1]),
                 map: currentMap,
                 icon: '/img/sticker/empty.png',
                 shadow: '/img/sticker/bubble_shadow.png',
                 transparent: '/img/sticker/bubble_transparent.png',
                 draggable: false,
                 raiseOnDrag: false,
                 labelContent: ""+number,
                 labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
                 labelClass: "mapIconLabel", // the CSS class for the label
                 labelInBackground: false
                });
            }
```

Since I added **mapIconLabel** class to the marker I can add some css rules in my css:

```
.mapIconLabel {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'DINNextRoundedLTProMediumRegular';
}
```

And here is the result:

[image: MarkerWithIconAndLabel]

Comment: To people finding this years later:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/ has multiple revisions of what I assume is the same source code. v1.1.5 worked for me, yet v1.1.9 didn't so if the above doesn't work, maybe try an older version.

Thanks for the info though Jakob

Comment: I got problems with MarkerWithLabel when adding large number of marker to the map with custom label position.

Answer (score 28):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on answers but wanted to note that the Google Chart API has been deprecated.

From the [API homepage](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/):

> The Infographics portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially
>   deprecated as of April 20, 2012.

Comment: The Google Chart API has *not* been deprecated, just the Image Charts and Infographics tools. That may have been used by dave1010's answer, but the latest Google Maps gives you a better solution now anyway (see John's answer).

Answer (score 21):

You may want to download a set of numbered icons from the sources provided at this site:

- [Google Marker Icons](http://jg.org/mapping/icons.html)

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Demo</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() {

      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

      var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker' + i + '.png',
                      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                      new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

          var location = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              title: location[0],
              zIndex: location[3]
          });
      }
    }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize();"> 
    <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:500px;"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot from the above example:

[image: Google Numbered Marker Icons]

Note that you can easily add a shadow behind the markers. You may want to check the example at the [Google Maps API Reference: Complex Markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#ComplexIcons) for more info about this.

Comment: I'd like to add text on top, not just use numbered images. Is that possible?

Answer (score 17):

This has now been added to the Mapping documentation and requires no third party code.

You can combine these two samples:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

To get code like this:

```
var labelIndex = 0;
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';

function initialize() {
  var bangalore = { lat: 12.97, lng: 77.59 };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: bangalore
  });

  // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });

  // Add a marker at the center of the map.
  addMarker(bangalore, map);
}

// Adds a marker to the map.
function addMarker(location, map) {
  // Add the marker at the clicked location, and add the next-available label
  // from the array of alphabetical characters.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex],
    map: map,
    icon: 'image.png'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Note that if you have more than 35 markers, this method will not work as the label only shows the first character (using A-Z and 0-9 makes 35). Please vote for this [Google Maps Issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578) to request that this restriction be lifted.

Comment: 'image.png' is not working for me.  Where is this image coming from?  Thanks

Comment: image.png your own image file that sites along side this script. If the file is not local or relative you set a full url e.g. http://yourdomain.com/images/image.png

Comment: Is there anyway I can load my local image file?  Where do I place it?  Thanks a lot

Comment: You can host your image in the same place as this script, if you are testing on your own machine just place it in the folder next to the html/javascript file.

Comment: This doesn't work if labelIndex > 9. As the docs state, marker.label only shows the first character. (@IYM-14, you might have a bug if you used this)

Comment: You can convert the index to a letter to get 26 extra to a total of 35 but yes this seems to be a limit

Comment: I really can't believe Google still hasn't made any effort to get their pins to at least handle double digits.  Trying to handle this dynamically through Javascript is a huge pain.

Answer (score 12):

I did this using a solution similar to @ZuzEL.

Instead of use the default solution (http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=7|FF0000|000000), you can create these images as you wish, using JavaScript, without any server-side code.

Google google.maps.Marker accepts Base64 for its icon property. With this we can create a valid Base64 from a SVG.

### [image]

You can see the code to produce the same as this image in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jep5mVN3DsVRgtlz1GGQ?p=preview

```js
var markers = [
  [1002, -14.2350040, -51.9252800],
  [2000, -34.028249, 151.157507],
  [123, 39.0119020, -98.4842460],
  [50, 48.8566140, 2.3522220],
  [22, 38.7755940, -9.1353670],
  [12, 12.0733335, 52.8234367],
];

function initializeMaps() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  markers.forEach(function(point) {
    generateIcon(point[0], function(src) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[2]);

      bounds.extend(pos);

      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: src
      });
    });
  });

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

var generateIconCache = {};

function generateIcon(number, callback) {
  if (generateIconCache[number] !== undefined) {
    callback(generateIconCache[number]);
  }

  var fontSize = 16,
    imageWidth = imageHeight = 35;

  if (number >= 1000) {
    fontSize = 10;
    imageWidth = imageHeight = 55;
  } else if (number < 1000 && number > 100) {
    fontSize = 14;
    imageWidth = imageHeight = 45;
  }

  var svg = d3.select(document.createElement('div')).append('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 54.4 54.4')
    .append('g')

  var circles = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', '27.2')
    .attr('cy', '27.2')
    .attr('r', '21.2')
    .style('fill', '#2063C6');

  var path = svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M27.2,0C12.2,0,0,12.2,0,27.2s12.2,27.2,27.2,27.2s27.2-12.2,27.2-27.2S42.2,0,27.2,0z M6,27.2 C6,15.5,15.5,6,27.2,6s21.2,9.5,21.2,21.2c0,11.7-9.5,21.2-21.2,21.2S6,38.9,6,27.2z')
    .attr('fill', '#FFFFFF');

  var text = svg.append('text')
    .attr('dx', 27)
    .attr('dy', 32)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('style', 'font-size:' + fontSize + 'px; fill: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-weight: bold')
    .text(number);

  var svgNode = svg.node().parentNode.cloneNode(true),
    image = new Image();

  d3.select(svgNode).select('clippath').remove();

  var xmlSource = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgNode);

  image.onload = (function(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      dataURL;

    d3.select(canvas)
      .attr('width', imageWidth)
      .attr('height', imageHeight);

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    generateIconCache[number] = dataURL;

    callback(dataURL);
  }).bind(this, imageWidth, imageHeight);

  image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(encodeURIComponent(xmlSource).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
    return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
  }));
}

initializeMaps();
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

In this demo I create the SVG using D3.js, then transformed SVG to Canvas, so I can resize the image as I want and after that I get Base64 from canvas' toDataURL method.

All this demo was based on my fellow **@thiago-mata** code. Kudos for him.

Comment: Thanks for this. This didn't work in Firefox, I fixed this in http://plnkr.co/edit/CiHVNYGXRqa8pHhy4eDY?p=preview - what's needed was to define width and height at the d3 svg.

Comment: Neither @estevao_lucas or @Arie solutions work in IE11. "SecurityError" on line:

`dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();`

Comment: You are right. Personally I ended up using a different approach. I simply put a div with a background image on a custom marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#draw

Comment: Adding a 52kb js file just to add map markers... jesus

Answer (score 9):

## How about this? (year 2015)

1) Get a custom marker image.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "/markers/blank_pin.png";
```

2) Create a `canvas` in `RAM` and draw this image on it

```
imageObj.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
}
```

3) Write anything above it

```
context.font = "40px Arial";
context.fillText("54", 17, 55);
```

4) Get raw data from canvas and provide it to Google API instead of URL

```
var image = {
    url: canvas.toDataURL(),
 };
 new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    icon: image
 });
```

[image]

Full code:

```
function addComplexMarker(map, position, label, callback){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "/markers/blank_pin.png";
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

        //Adjustable parameters
        context.font = "40px Arial";
        context.fillText(label, 17, 55);
        //End

        var image = {
            url: canvas.toDataURL(),
            size: new google.maps.Size(80, 104),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 104)
        };
        // the clickable region of the icon.
        var shape = {
            coords: [1, 1, 1, 104, 80, 104, 80 , 1],
            type: 'poly'
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            zIndex: 9999
        });
        callback && callback(marker)
    };
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution but I must add that using imageObj.onload is asynchroneous and will probably cause some problems within a loop.  A work around would be to load the png into a browser and use Developer Tools to select image data (use Ctrl A).  Then just setting imageObj.src to "data:image/png;base64,paste_the_really_long_image_ data_string_here";
This way can avoid using onload function and it is faster.

Comment: what about performance? how will it run on the map with 200 markers?

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps version 3 has built-in support for marker labels.  No need to generate your own images anymore or implement 3rd party classes. [Marker Labels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite feasible to generate labeled icons server-side, if you have some programming skills.  You'll need the GD library at the server, in addition to PHP.  Been working well for me for several years now, but admittedly tricky to get the icon images in synch.

I do that via AJAX by sending the few parameters to define the blank icon and the text and color as well as bgcolor to be applied.  Here's my PHP:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
//$img_url = "./icons/gen_icon5.php?blank=7&text=BB";

function do_icon ($icon, $text, $color) {
$im = imagecreatefrompng($icon);
imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

$len = strlen($text);
$p1 = ($len <= 2)? 1:2 ;
$p2 = ($len <= 2)? 3:2 ;
$px = (imagesx($im) - 7 * $len) / 2 + $p1;
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$contrast = ($color)? imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255): imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // white on dark?

imagestring($im, $p2, $px, 3, $text, $contrast);    // imagestring  ( $image, $font, $x, $y, $string, $color)

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
$icons =   array("black.png", "blue.png", "green.png", "red.png", "white.png", "yellow.png", "gray.png", "lt_blue.png", "orange.png");      // 1/9/09
$light =   array( TRUE,         TRUE,       FALSE,       FALSE,     FALSE,      FALSE,      FALSE,          FALSE,      FALSE);     // white text?

$the_icon = $icons[$_GET['blank']];             // 0 thru 8 (note: total 9)
$the_text = substr($_GET['text'], 0, 3);        // enforce 2-char limit
do_icon ($the_icon, $the_text,$light[$_GET['blank']] );
```

It's invoked client-side via something like the following:
    var image_file = "./our_icons/gen_icon.php?blank=" + escape(icons[color]) + "&text=" + iconStr;

Comment: This actually isn't all that bad a solution. It only takes ~30ms to generate each marker on our setup. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents showing how to use the [Google Charts API](http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1285227235/google-maps-markers-with-numbers-or-text) to solve this problem.

Comment: Clever! I already have my numbered images, but I like this approach a lot.

Comment: This is why you need to copy your code's solution into the answer box when answering.

Answer (score 1):

Google's latest update just made mine and other people's custom solutions obsolete:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/basic-customization
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/graphic-markers

```js
// A marker using a Font Awesome icon for the glpyh.
const icon = document.createElement("div");

icon.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pizza-slice fa-lg"></i>';

const faPinView = new google.maps.marker.PinView({
  glyph: icon,
  glyphColor: "#ff8300",
  background: "#FFD514",
  borderColor: "#ff8300",
});

const faMarkerView = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
  map,
  position: { lat: 37.412, lng: -122.095829650878 },
  content: faPinView.element,
  title: "A marker using a FontAwesome icon for the glyph.",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@dave1010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788519/662581) answer but with updated `https` links.

Numbered marker:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=7|FF0000|000000
```

Text marker:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=1|0|FF0000|12|_|Marker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Marker With Label option in google-maps-utility-library-v3.
[image]

Just refer https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Here are custom icons with the updated "visual refresh" style that you can generate quickly via a simple .vbs script. I also included a large pre-generated set that you can use immediately with multiple color options: https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers

Use the following format when linking to the GitHub-hosted image files:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_[color][character].png
```

**color**
red, black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, white, yellow

**character**
A-Z, 1-100, !, @, $, +, -, =, (%23 = #), (%25 = %), (%26 = &), (blank = •)

**Examples:**

[image: red1] 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_red1.png

[image: blue2]
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_blue2.png

[image: green3]
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_green3.png

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the best way to do it.
Use [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to create the svg and then use the function toDataURL() that creates the graphics data to include as icon.
Note that I use the SlidingMarker class for the marker that gives me nice movement of the marker.
With Snap.svg you can create any kind of graphics and your map will look fantastic.

```
var s = Snap(100, 100);
s.text(50, 50, store.name);
// Use more graphics here.
var marker = new SlidingMarker({
  position: {lat: store.lat, lng: store.lng},
  map: $scope.map,
  label: store.name, // you do not need this
  title: store.name, // nor this
  duration: 2000,
  icon: s.toDataURL()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EASIEST SOLUTION - USE SVG**

Works in: in **IE9**, **IE10**, FF, Chrome, Safari

(if you are using other browsers please "Run code snippet" and place a comment)

No external dependencies besides Google Maps API!

[image]

This is **quite** easy provided that you have your icon in **.svg** format. If that is the case just **add** appropriate text element and change its content to fit your needs with JS.

Add something like this to your `.svg` code (this is text "section" which will be later changed with JS):

```
<text id="1" fill="#20539F" font-family="NunitoSans-ExtraBold, Nunito Sans" font-size="18" font-weight="600" letter-spacing=".104" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="28">1</text>
```

**Example:** (partially copied from @EstevãoLucas)

**Important:**
Use correct `<text>` tag properties. Note `text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="28"` which center longer numbers (more info: [How to place and center text in an SVG rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546346/how-to-place-and-center-text-in-an-svg-rectangle))

Use `encodeURIComponent()` (this probably ensures compatibility with IE9 and 10)

```js
// Most important part (use output as Google Maps icon)
function getMarkerIcon(number) {
  // inline your SVG image with number variable
  var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"> <defs> <rect id="path-1" width="40" height="40"/> <mask id="mask-2" width="40" height="40" x="0" y="0" fill="white"> <use xlink:href="#path-1"/> </mask> </defs> <g id="Page-1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <g id="Phone-Portrait---320" transform="translate(-209 -51)"> <g id="Group" transform="translate(209 51)"> <use id="Rectangle" fill="#FFEB3B" stroke="#F44336" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#mask-2)" xlink:href="#path-1"/> <text id="1" fill="#20539F" font-family="NunitoSans-ExtraBold, Nunito Sans" font-size="18" font-weight="600" letter-spacing=".104" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="28">' + number + '</text> </g> </g> </g> </svg>';
  // use SVG without base64 see: https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/
  return 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
}

// Standard Maps API code
var markers = [
  [1, -14.2350040, -51.9252800],
  [2, -34.028249, 151.157507],
  [3, 39.0119020, -98.4842460],
  [5, 48.8566140, 2.3522220],
  [9, 38.7755940, -9.1353670],
  [12, 12.0733335, 52.8234367],
];

function initializeMaps() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  markers.forEach(function(point) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[2]);

      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: getMarkerIcon(point[0]),         
      });

      bounds.extend(pos);
  });

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

initializeMaps();
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>        
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

More info about inline SVG in Google Maps: https://robert.katzki.de/posts/inline-svg-as-google-maps-marker

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are those still looking for this but finding Google Dynamic icons deprecated and other map-icon libraries just a little bit too ugly.

To add a simple marker with any number inside using a URL. In Google Drive using the Google My Maps, it creates numbered icons when using a map layer that is set to 'Sequence of Numbers' and then adding markers/points on the map.

Looking at the source code, Google has their own way of doing it through a URL:

```
https://mt.google.com/vt/icon/name=icons/onion/SHARED-mymaps-container-bg_4x.png,icons/onion/SHARED-mymaps-container_4x.png,icons/onion/1738-blank-sequence_4x.png&highlight=ff000000,0288D1,ff000000&scale=2.0&color=ffffffff&psize=15&text=56&font=fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
```

[Above URL](https://mt.google.com/vt/icon/name=icons/onion/SHARED-mymaps-container-bg_4x.png,icons/onion/SHARED-mymaps-container_4x.png,icons/onion/1738-blank-sequence_4x.png&highlight=ff000000,0288D1,ff000000&scale=2.0&color=ffffffff&psize=15&text=56&font=fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf)

[image]

I haven't played extensively with it but by changing the hex color codes in the 'highlight' parameter(color parameter does not change the color as you may think), the 'text' value can be set to any string and you can make a nice round icon with any number/value inside. I'm sure the other parameters may be of use too.

One caveat with this approach, who knows when Google will remove this URL from the world!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // initiate Google maps
    initialize();
    // make a .hover event
    $('#markers_info .marker').hover(
      // mouse in
      function () {
        // first we need to know which <div class="marker"></div> we hovered
        var index = $('#markers_info .marker').index(this);
        markers[index].setIcon(highlightedIcon());
      },
      // mouse out
      function () {
        // first we need to know which <div class="marker"></div> we hovered
        var index = $('#markers_info .marker').index(this);
        markers[index].setIcon(activeIcon());
      }

      );
  });
  /**
    Google Maps stuff
    */
    var markerData = [   // the order of these markers must be the same as the <div class="marker"></div> elements
    {lat: 43.0628, lng: -89.4165, title: 'Manneken Pis'},
    {lat: 43.0749, lng: -89.3927, title: 'Jeanneke Pis'},
    {lat: 43.0731, lng: -89.4012, title: 'Grand Place'},
    {lat: 43.0766, lng: -89.4125, title: 'Manneken Pis'},
    {lat: 43.0775, lng: -89.4457, title: 'Jeanneke Pis'},
    {lat: 43.0972, lng: -89.5043, title: 'Grand Place'},
    {lat: 43.1351, lng: -89.4385, title: 'Manneken Pis'},
    {lat: 43.1267, lng: -89.3203, title: 'Jeanneke Pis'}
    ];
    var label = "1";
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.0731,-89.4360),// United state,madison long lat
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      new google.maps.Size(49,100)
      for (var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {
        markers.push(
          new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i].lat, markerData[i].lng),
            title: markerData[i].title,
            map: map,
            label: {
              text: label,
              // Adding the custom label
              fontFamily: 'Raleway, sans-serif' + label,
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: "16px",
              fontweight:"bold"
            },
            icon: activeIcon()
          })
          );
      }
    }
    // functions that return icons.  Make or find your own markers.
    function activeIcon() {
      return {
       path:
       "M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0z",
       fillColor: "#2f8aac",
       fillOpacity: 1,
       strokeWeight: 0,
       rotation: 0,
       scale: 0.08,
       anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
       labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(200, 200)

     };
   }

    // functions that return icons.  When hovering at the sidebar.
   function highlightedIcon() {
    return {
      path:
      "M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0z",
      fillColor: "#d22a15",
      fillOpacity: 5,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      rotation: 0,
      scale: 0.12,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(200, 200)
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.