# Google Map Marker with custom numbering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a Google Maps marker function that successfully creates markers on a map like this:

```
 // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(point,html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point,{title:html});
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
  }
```

Here is a tinyurl of the exiting code:  http://tinyurl.com/b8f9b4l

Using this solution: [Google maps: place number in marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890670/google-maps-place-number-in-marker)

I've updated this line of code but it is not numbering.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var marker = new GMarker(point,{title:html,icon:'icon: \'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+ (position) +'|FF776B|000000',});
```

Comment: You're using API v2 which is going to stop working in about 3 weeks time: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/  Strongly suggest you rewrite it ASAP to API v3

Comment: Yep..that is what I ended up doing...the code was a mess anyway.  Sometimes being forced to rewrite works out okay :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon property just needs to be the url. You don't need the extra "icon:", and you should drop the extra comma at the end (IE seems to throw an exception when it finds a dangling comma). Also, the parenthesis you don't need - but probably aren't hurting anything.

```
{
title:html,
icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + position +'|FF776B|000000'
}
```

I see where you got the idea. Idk why s/he got a point for that. The extra "icon:" messes it up.

Try this as a test, it should make sure you don't have any problems with the variables inside the url.

```
{
title:html,
icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=4|FF776B|000000'
}
```

Comment: Still something wrong with it..when I add the icon: it defaults the map to a World view with now markers: http://tinyurl.com/arsy2wb

Comment: Where are you getting "position" from? I don't see that variable in your code. You might want to use your "pos" var, but you may need to pass that into your function like you did "point" and "html". For a quick test, just replace your "position" with a number in the url.

Comment: its in the URL like this for each marker: ?q=@53,-2&q=@53.5,-2.5

Comment: you're not trying to display "53,-2" in the marker icon are you? You can probably only show up to a two digit number. As a test, put this as the url for the icon: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=4|FF776B|000000 then we go from there.

Comment: Not at all, check the URL here and you'll see.  I'm trying to just add numbers to the markers already displayed in the order they appear in the URL:  http://tinyurl.com/b8f9b4l

Comment: I see what you are saying. It looks to me like you just copied the line form the other question straightaway - keeping the variable they used "position" when it isn't in your code. Maybe I am missing something,  but I thin you need to replace "position" with whatever var contains your position number.