# GoogleMaps : Design Custom Price Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I'm developing a mobile application using ionic and have a requirement to show places in google maps with price marker like this :

[image]

I wrote a very basic code to integrate google map with markers.

**MapController**

```
controller('MapController', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $log, $timeout, $state) {

    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 12.9250, longitude: 77.5938 }, zoom: 8, window: { show: false } };
    $scope.options = { scrollwheel: false };

    $scope.markerEvents = {
        events: {
            dragend: function(marker, eventName, args) {
                var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                var lon = marker.getPosition().lng();
                $log.log(lat);
                $log.log(lon);

                $scope.marker.options = {
                    draggable: true,
                    labelContent: "lat: " + $scope.marker.coords.latitude + ' ' + 'lon: ' + $scope.marker.coords.longitude,
                    labelAnchor: "100 0",
                    labelClass: "marker-labels"
                };
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.markers = [{

        id: 0,
        coords: {
            latitude: 12.8421,
            longitude: 77.6631
        },
        options: { draggable: false, icon: '',  labelClass: 'marker_labels', labelAnchor: '12 60', labelContent: '$400' }

    }, {
        id: 1,
        coords: {
            latitude: 12.1481,
            longitude: 77.5631
        },
          options: { draggable: false, icon: '',  labelClass: 'marker_labels', labelAnchor: '12 60', labelContent: '$600' }

    }, {
        id: 2,
        coords: {
            latitude: 12.3411,
            longitude: 77.4631
        },
          options: { draggable: false, icon: '',  labelClass: 'marker_labels', labelAnchor: '12 60', labelContent: '$550' }

    }, {
        id: 3,
        coords: {
            latitude: 12.5420,
            longitude: 77.3631
        },
          options: { draggable: false, icon: '',  labelClass: 'marker_labels', labelAnchor: '12 60', labelContent: '$900' }
    }];
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Maps">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' draggable="true" options="options">
                <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="markerEvents.events" idkey="marker.id" click="onMarkerClick">
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Currently, I'm getting default marker icon which I want to hide and instead just show the price.

I've been searching long for clear information about the right way of implementing custom marker, but the result I get did not satisfied me.

So what should I do to implement this?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki The one which I showed in image..something like that

Comment: So its not your case in picture? show us how yours looks like, and please add your code also.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I've added the code..and I want my maker to look same as I shown in image..

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37582234/1769657

Answer (score 4):

By extending the `google.maps.OverlayView` class you can create and customise any marker using css/html. You can create your own directive for your custom marker that extends this class, for example [this](https://www.reonomy.com/creating-custom-google-map-markers-with-angular/) tutorial might help you.

Another option is to use different library for angularjs google maps, for example [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/#/!custom-marker-custom-style.html) , which already contain support for custom markers.