# Adding Text inside SVG icon for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, svg, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a custom Google Maps icon using SVG. I've gotten this far. However, all information online about SVG that I can find uses this kind of notation: <> <>.

I'm trying to do the SVG inside a JS object. Can anyone help me by telling me what this type of SVG is called so I can find somewhere to learn it?

My goal is to be able to add text inside the circle, but right now my text element does not work. Thank you!

```
var icon = {
    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: .5,
    text: "57"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a single character inside your SVG marker, that is supported natively by the Google Maps Javascript API v3 [Marker (a "labelled marker"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels).

Related question if you want multiple characters: [Google maps Marker Label with multiple characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467212/google-maps-marker-label-with-multiple-characters)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.405, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: .6,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      scale: .5,
      text: "57"
    },
    label: "B"
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add custom markers to google maps:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
  });

  //define your marker
  var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
  };

 //put the marker on the map
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: goldStar,
    map: map
  });
 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                     'lorem ipsum </div>'

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: contentString
 });

 marker.addListener('click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
 });
}
```

for SVG reference you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html)

here's a Plunker if you want play around: https://plnkr.co/edit/W5C0NVMrj5larSVNsmFy?p=preview

Comment: Ahh sorry if I wasn't clear. I appreciate your code. I have all of that already, I'm just trying to figure out what the SVG attribute is for text. I want to add a text element to my SVG so that each circle is numbered.

Comment: For SVG text reference you can see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html. But google markers accept just paths. You can add listners to your markers