# How can I show label/title for marker permanently in Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, label, google-maps-markers

I want to display Markers on Google map with title displayed under them as shown in picture:

[image: Sample in ver 2]

Now this I read was possible in v2 using ELabel but is deprecated in v3. Is there any possible way to show some text under icons of markers in Google Maps V3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in an other post which worked perfectly for me.

[Add numbering label to google map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562506/add-numbering-label-to-google-map-marker)

Answer (score 83):

Since at least October 2016, the official API provides a way to add permanently visible labels that are longer than one letter. See [this reply by a Google project member](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578#c28).

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  label: 'Hello world',
});
```

By default, the result looks like:

[image: Example image]

Pretty unreadable. Fortunately the API also allows a [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels) object instead of a plain string:

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  label: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    text: 'Hello world',
  },
});
```

Snippet above yields the following result:

[image: A white, bold label at the middle of the marker]

However, the original question asked if the label could be located below the marker. The MarkerLabel docs mention this is possible with a custom icon and `labelOrigin` property. If we want to use the default icon, one is [available at GitHub](https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers). Let us add the icon object:

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  label: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    text: 'Hello world',
  },
  icon: {
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(11, 50),
    url: 'default_marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(22, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 40),
  },
});
```

This results:

[image: A white, bold label below the marker]

Pretty good! However, this whole approach has a shortcoming that the box in the original question does not have: readability with each map type. If the map type is changed from the satellite to the default the resulting label is hard to read:

[image: A white, bold label below the marker against white background]

An easy but not perfect way to avoid the low contrast in the both types is to set `color: 'gray'`:

[image: Grey labels]

However, the gray color fails near urban areas. A better option would be to apply `text-shadow` CSS property to draw black linings for the white text. However, I cannot find a way to apply the property to the labels because few DOM elements created by Google Maps define a class:

[image: DOM elements]

The best option I came up to is to detect changes in the map type and update label color for each marker:

```
map.addListener('maptypeid_changed', function () {
  var typeToColor, type, color, k, label;

  typeToColor = {
    'terrain': 'black',
    'roadmap': 'black',
    'hybrid': 'white',
    'satellite': 'white',
  };

  type = map.getMapTypeId();
  color = typeToColor[type];

  for (k in markers) {
    if (markers.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      label = markers[k].getLabel();
      label.color = color;
      markers[k].setLabel(label);
    }
  }
});
```

However, even this would fail on snowy or cloudy satellite imagery. I think it is still good enough in most of the cases. Nevertheless, it is nice to have the ability to display visible labels with the official API, without any plugins :)

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen, structured, descriptive, relevent screenshots and good solution. If u could give 2 up votes i would

Answer (score 3):

You can't! But there's another part of maps API you can use to have permanently displayed text attached to your markers (without requiring any third party component), it's called infoWindow. Have a look at this for sample code & see it in action: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure

If you dare using third party code, then here's something that is closer from the look & feel you want: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Comment: As web developers, aren't we always using 3rd party code? No one's programming html forms with Assembly ;)

Comment: This was perfect, ty! We shouldn't need to pull in extra garbage when the api already provides it.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following:

[MarkerWithLabel.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/)

[image: example] ( the image is just a flag.png file)

Using javascript in my X.html document

it looks something like this....

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .labels {
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            width: 6em;
            border: 1px solid black;
            white-space: normal;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&amp;sensor=true"></script>
    <!--MarkerwithLabelClass - adjust the path!! -->
    <script src="YourPathHere/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//insert standaard initializing of googlemaps here
//and other windows.onload function
window.onload = function Initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 }
         function CreateMarker(lat, long, titel, label, image, anchorY, anchorX){

                   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(long));//I use parseFloat cause my parameters are strings(coming from JSON-string)
                    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                        zIndex: 1,
                        title: titel,
                        position: latlng,
                        draggable: false,
                        icon: image,
                        labelContent: label,
                        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, -2),
                        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                        labelStyle: { opacity: 0.80 }
                    });

                    return marker;
    }
 </script>
```

Read up on license info for google maps API here : https://www.google.com/intx/en_uk/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html

Comment: If you download the markerwithlabel.js and put it permanently on your own server and link to that path, it wont change unless you do so. And the google api is gna be reverse compatibel. So I wouldn't expect problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the same principle as in this [example](https://github.com/beekay-/gmaps-samples-v3/blob/master/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.html). Instead of listening to the mouse events you should create a new custom control for each marker and then position it below the marker. Hope it works out.

Comment: The example is a dead link