# api google maps V3 show title

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I use this code on my site.
It show map with markers and when you tap on marker you go to another page.
And you see title when you put cursor on marker, i need that title always been shown.

```js
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var points = [
["Page 1", 55.771683, 37.571274, 1, 'link to page 1'],
["Page 2", 55.7636, 37.606, 1, 'link to page 1']
   ];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
var shape = {
coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
type: 'poly'
};
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var flag = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
'http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/Google_Maps_Marker.png',
new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 19)
);
var place = locations[i];
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
icon: flag,
shape: shape,
title: place[0],
zIndex: place[3],
url: place[4]
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
// alert('go to ' + this.url); //
window.location.href = this.url;
});
} 
}

function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.766731,37.6010157,14),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
setMarkers(map, points);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

My question is i need that title -> (title: place[0]) allways show.
Now, when i use my code i see title just when i move cursor on marker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i show label/title for marker permanently in Google Maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603623/how-can-i-show-label-title-for-marker-permanently-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: I suppose that my question isn't duplication because i need show title depend of marker.