# How to remove marker label in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have markers with labels like below:

[image: Marker with white label]

The code is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40472150/638546):

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  label: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    text: 'Hello world',
  },
  icon: {
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(11, 50),
    url: 'default_marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(22, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 40),
  },
});
```

What I need in my project is to remove labels of certain markers. However, the [official API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels) seem to discuss only about adding the label. So, how to remove a label of a labeled marker?

Answer (score 3):

After a little experimentation, the following seems to remove the label:

```
m.setLabel(null);
```

It is similar to how the markers are removed from the map:

```
m.setMap(null);
```

Update: one thing to keep in mind though, is that `m.getLabel()` returns `undefined` until the label is set with `m.setLabel(...)`. After calling `m.setLabel(null)`, a call to `m.getLabel()` will return `null` instead.

Comment: I think this version is still experimental so that may change with many other things. But still finally we'll have builtin label support.