# Binding Google Maps API to existing business on Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used to use an iFrame to embed a Google Map in a web page, but have recently switched to the JavaScript API to give myself more flexibility.

I am loading the map using the co-ordinates, which is working relatively well.

However, when I view a business on Google maps or in an iFrame for that matter, I can see the business I'm trying to focus on, highlighted in red:

[image]

But I can't seem to achieve this with the API -- which sometimes doesn't show the business name at all, let alone highlight it red. I've used DHL as an example here.

[image]

How can I 'bind' the map to a business location using the JS API?

My current script looks much like the one provided by the Google walkthrough pages:

```
function initialize() {
    var longLat = { lat: 52.8004265, lng: -1.6334708},
        mapOptions = {
          center: longLat,
          zoom: 18,
          scrollwheel: false,
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions
    );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: longLat,
        map: map,
        title:"DHL"
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: But Why you need an iframe?

Comment: @ngDeveloper I ***don't*** want to use an iFrame

Comment: I don't quite know if that's what you want, but here is the documentation on how to show place details. I have never worked with it though: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Answer (score 0):

You can attach [**infowindow**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) to your marker and display the business name in that way. Here is an [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)
And here's another example using customized label as a marker, and it can contain the business name. [**Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562506/add-numbering-label-to-google-map-marker)