# Highlight an existing business on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of store addresses, and I'm trying to create a map out of it.
Using the Places API I am able to retrieve most of the informations and manually create and place the markers on the map:

```js
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.findPlaceFromQuery({
  query: '212 Enterprise Dr, Rockaway, Frank Pizza',
  fields: ['all']
}, onPlaceFound);
```

However I'd like to select the original marker instead of overlapping a new one.

That is because I want the user to be able to open the default info window with store phone number, directions and stuff.

I know that I can re-create it, but it feels kinda lame since all the info is already there.

[image: Original GM Marker]
[image: Custom Marker]

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606137/binding-google-maps-api-to-existing-business-on-google) ask about the same, yet no solution has been found.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search), which shows [findPlaceFromQuery()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery), the second parameter of `findPlaceFromQuery` should be a function where the first argument of that function is an Array of [placeResults](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult).

Therefore, after reviewing a link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceGeometry) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) your `onPlaceFound` function should be looking something like:

```
function onPlaceFound(placeResultsArray){
  const firstResult = placeResultsArray[0], firstIconURL = firstResult.icon;
  const latLng = firstResult.geometry.location, lat = latLng.lat(), lng = latLng.lng();
  // do stuff with those variables here
}
```

Of course, that does not select Google's result as a `Marker`, but now you have the actual `icon`, and `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: I know, and that's what I am able to do right now. But what i want to do is to filter out the places and leave only / select the ones at the coordinates I get, and not to place a new marker

Comment: Well, there you have it. Nobody has an answer to your problem. Google sucks.