# Align text inside SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have SVG element, and I want align text by x and y axis inside.

```html
<svg width="90px" height="90px" viewBox="-9 -3 90 76" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <g>
     <text>Lorem</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can i do this? Thanks for any tips.

P.S. I can't change viewBox and sizes of SVG element or move text outside from g element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this what you are looking for

```
     <text x="45" y="0">Lorem</text>
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the snippet below:

```html
<svg width="90px" height="90px" viewBox="-9 -3 90 76" style="border: 1px solid black;">
   <g>
      <text x="40%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Lorem</text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

You could find more info in this answer: [How to place and center text in an SVG rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546346/how-to-place-and-center-text-in-an-svg-rectangle)