# how to add text to the right side of the Piechart in Highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am having a pie chart in which have legend at the bottom. i want to add the text at the right side of the pie chart.how to add it?. thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546346/how-to-place-and-center-text-in-an-svg-rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **SVGRenderer** feature to render a custom text wherever you want. If you want to have a responsive text I encourage to create it inside the **chart.events.render** callback, which triggers after each resize.

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      x,
      y;


    //check if label exist after window resize
    if (chart.label) {
      chart.label.destroy();
    };

    y = 80;
    x = chart.clipBox.width - 100;
    chart.label = chart.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: red">styled</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', x, y)
      .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px'
      })
      .add();
  }
}
```

### Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4fzyLn0r/2/

### API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

### API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sebastian Wedzel. i can add the text now but the problem is the text is not responsive while i resizing the screen.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: I made it to work after spending some time in this. thank you for answer and reply.

Comment: I have to add some dynamic text from ts file and it is of three to four lines. can it be possible with accomodate the space in the renderer.text? @ Sebastian Wędzel

Comment: set the useHTML to true and set the html <br> property in the text. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lqdrv4u0/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text