# How to wrap "SVG" element with background color around the text

Tags: html, svg, attributes

I have this code of HTML

```html
<div class="bubble" id="bubble-1">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="285px" height="67" viewBox="0 0 50 67"
  fill="none">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
    d="M149.738 16L140.5 0L131.262 16H4C1.79086 16 0 17.7909 0 20V63C0 65.2091 1.79086 67 4 67H163C165.209 67 167 65.2091 167 63V20C167 17.7909 165.209 16 163 16H149.738Z"
    fill="#FFF28D" />
      <text x="100%" y="50%" fill="#000" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"
      dy=".35em"> Some twxt here
      </text>
 </svg>
</div>
```

I would like to wrap all the text inside the background color, but it's seems that the text slides out.

How should I need to create this "SVG" HTML element clearly?

Comment: Add an extra path line, position text on that line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546346/how-to-place-and-center-text-in-an-svg-rectangle/71085150#71085150

Comment: SVG is probably not the best option: You won't be able to stretch/grow this speech bubble to fit more text. Better rebuild this in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The speech bubble is 167 wide and 67 height. Make the viewBox fit that size. In the x axes the text should be in the middle -- that if 50%. On the y axes the "pointer" of the speech bubble is 16 high, so the text must be placed in `(67 - 16) / 2 + 16` on the y axes.

```html
<div class="bubble" id="bubble-1">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="285" viewBox="0 0 167 67">
    <path d="M149.738 16L140.5 0L131.262 16H4C1.79086 16 0 17.7909 0 20V63C0 65.2091 1.79086 67 4 67H163C165.209 67 167 65.2091 167 63V20C167 17.7909 165.209 16 163 16H149.738Z"
    fill="#FFF28D" />
    <text x="50%" y="41.5" fill="#000" dominant-baseline="middel"
      text-anchor="middle">Some twxt here</text>
 </svg>
</div>
```