# How to make waypoint marker to bounce when pointed on the outside text?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We need help.Currently our waypoint bouncing code works when the mouse is pointed on the waypoint marker. We want it to bounce when the mouse is pointed on the outside text.Check the screenshot link: http://screencast.com/t/NPucK50C2y

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?  key=AIzaSyBADaZ6uLiLXx0FokaKyQeV15blaiLDKUI&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers=new Array();
    var map;
   function initialize() {
  var bounceTimer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   suppressMarkers : true
 });
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
   zoom:7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [ { featureType:'water', stylers:[{color:'#46bcec'},{visibility:'on'}] },{ featureType:'landscape', stylers:[{color:'#f2f2f2'}] },{ featureType:'road', stylers: [{saturation:-100},{lightness:45}] },{ featureType:'road.highway', stylers: [{visibility:'simplified'}] },{ featureType:'road.arterial', elementType:'labels.icon', stylers: [{visibility:'off'}] },{ featureType:'administrative', elementType:'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color:'#444444'}] },{ featureType:'transit', stylers:[{visibility:'off'}] },{ featureType:'poi', stylers:[{visibility:'off'}] }],
        });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 // directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
  var waypts = [{location:new google.maps.LatLng(1.28644, 103.84663), stopover:true},   {location:new google.maps.LatLng(1.28627, 103.85927), stopover:true}];
 var request = {
  origin: new google.maps.LatLng(1.30365, 103.85256), 
  destination: new google.maps.LatLng(1.29411, 103.84631),
  waypoints: waypts,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var markerCounter = 1;
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    // add custom markers
    var route = response.routes[0];
     // start marker
    addMarker(route.legs[0].start_location, markerCounter++);
    // the rest
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
      addMarker(route.legs[i].end_location, markerCounter++);
     }
   }
  });
  function addMarker(position, i) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436484/how-can-i-create-numbered-map-markers-in-google-maps-v3 for numbered icons
     icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + i + '|fff|000000',
     position: position,
     map: map
     });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        if (this.getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {

       //            Because of the google maps bug of moving cursor several times over and out of marker
        //            causes bounce animation to break - we use small timer before triggering the bounce animation
        //            

        clearTimeout(bounceTimer);

        var that = this;
        bounceTimer = setTimeout(function(){
             that.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        },
        500);
       }
   });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
         this.setAnimation(null);
        }
        // If we already left marker, no need to bounce when timer is ready
        clearTimeout(bounceTimer);
     });

    markers.push(marker);

    return marker;
   }
  }

   /*function scrollToMarker(index) {
    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());
   }*/

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>

   <body>
   <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left; width: 950px; height: 400px; float: left; color:">  </div> 
    <!--<div onclick=scrollToMarker(0)>Pointer 1</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(1)>Pointer 2</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(2)>Pointer 3</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(3)>Pointer 4</div>-->
  <div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;">Pointer 1</div>
  <div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;">Pointer 2</div>
  <div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;">Pointer 3</div>
  <div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;">Pointer 4</div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(1)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(1)">Pointer 1</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(2)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(2)">Pointer 2</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(3)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(3)">Pointer 3</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(4)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(4)">Pointer 4</div>

function stopBounceMarker(n) {
  n=n-1;
  if (markers[n].getAnimation() != null) {
     markers[n].setAnimation(null);
  }
}
function startBounceMarker(n) {
  n=n-1;
  if (markers[n].getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {
    markers[n].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ynf53L2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = new Array();
var map;

function initialize() {
  var bounceTimer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
      featureType: 'water',
      stylers: [{
        color: '#46bcec'
      }, {
        visibility: 'on'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      stylers: [{
        color: '#f2f2f2'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'road',
      stylers: [{
        saturation: -100
      }, {
        lightness: 45
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'simplified'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'road.arterial',
      elementType: 'labels.icon',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'administrative',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{
        color: '#444444'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'transit',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'poi',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }],
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  // directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
  var waypts = [{
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(1.28644, 103.84663),
    stopover: true
  }, {
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(1.28627, 103.85927),
    stopover: true
  }];
  var request = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(1.30365, 103.85256),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(1.29411, 103.84631),
    waypoints: waypts,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var markerCounter = 1;
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      // add custom markers
      var route = response.routes[0];
      // start marker
      addMarker(route.legs[0].start_location, markerCounter++);
      // the rest
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        addMarker(route.legs[i].end_location, markerCounter++);
      }
    }
  });

  function addMarker(position, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436484/how-can-i-create-numbered-map-markers-in-google-maps-v3 for numbered icons
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + i + '|fff|000000',
      position: position,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      if (this.getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {

        //            Because of the google maps bug of moving cursor several times over and out of marker
        //            causes bounce animation to break - we use small timer before triggering the bounce animation
        //            

        clearTimeout(bounceTimer);

        var that = this;
        bounceTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            that.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
          },
          500);
      }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
        this.setAnimation(null);
      }
      // If we already left marker, no need to bounce when timer is ready
      clearTimeout(bounceTimer);
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    return marker;
  }
}

/*function scrollToMarker(index) {
 map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());
}*/

function stopBounceMarker(n) {
  n = n - 1;
  if (markers[n].getAnimation() != null) {
    markers[n].setAnimation(null);
  }
}

function startBounceMarker(n) {
  n = n - 1;
  if (markers[n].getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {
    markers[n].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left; width: 950px; height: 400px; float: left; color:"> </div>
<!--<div onclick=scrollToMarker(0)>Pointer 1</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(1)>Pointer 2</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(2)>Pointer 3</div>
  <div onclick=scrollToMarker(3)>Pointer 4</div>-->
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(1)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(1)">Pointer 1</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(2)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(2)">Pointer 2</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(3)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(3)">Pointer 3</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="startBounceMarker(4)" onmouseout="stopBounceMarker(4)">Pointer 4</div>
```